# Azure Logic Apps, Getting Started Config

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I created a new logic app with a Service Bus connector configured to read an Azure Queue message and the portal let me configure it.

Now I want to edit that config info. Where is the Queue and subscription info stored?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Service Bus connector encrypts the Keys and puts them in the DefaultValue element of the parameters:

[image]

And I think for security reasons they don't decrypt the values and if you need to change them you should remove that step and add it back again...